# How many of the $1000$ smallest natural numbers leave a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$ and a remainder of $4$ when divided by $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I found that the general form of number is $N=21k+32$. As per question $N=21k+32 \leq 1000$ which will give the result as $k \leq 46.09$ so there should be $46$ such natural numbers which will statisfy the condition given in the question but the correct answer provided is $48$. What have I done wrong? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The general form is $N=21k-10$ where $k$ is a natural number. $N=21k+32$ misses $11$ and $32$.

Comment: @Saturday : How did you get to that general form? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ganit Have you learnt modular arithmetic before?

Comment: @AaaLol_dude No i am not familiar with modular arithmetic but thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Ganit basically modular arithmetic just shows how much remainder is left after dividing by a number. Therefore, $13 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$ as 13 leaves 6 after being divided by 7.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You first need to find a special solution: that is, one solution that satisfies the conditions. The only way for this is trial-and-error.

I see you have found $32$, so $32$ plus any multiple of $21$ (this could be  negative as well) is the general solution, and by the Chinese Remainder Theorem this is the only general solution.

$$N=21m+32$$

where $m$ is an **integer**. $N$ has to be positive so we have $m \ge -1$. We want to use a natural number in the general form, so substitute $m=k-2$ and $k$ will be a natural number.

$$\therefore N=21k-10$$

Comment: I recommend avoiding the phrase "the only way for this" in mathematical pedagogy, since it's hardly ever true. It doesn't promote creativity in the problem solving process.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> Try use a well known formula to solve this, most commonly known as CRT.

Answer:

> Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we get one unique solution of the question happening every 21 terms. This gives us 47 numbers that fit the question from 1-987. Now, getting the congruency, given from the asker, that $N\equiv 11 \pmod {21}$. Therefore, as $987+11 \leq 1000$, we add one to our final answer, giving us 48 numbers.

Tip (a spoil):

> The Chinese Remainder theorem only works for coprime numbers, so $x \pmod 2$ and $y \pmod 4$ would not work. However, this can easily be solved by removing a multiple of both numbers (only on one of the numbers), until both are coprime again. For example, $4,2$ would be turned into just $4$, while $6,4$ would be $4,3$. However, be careful not to remove the wrong number.

Comment: Why use the abbreviation when it is first mentioned only, and then the full name for every other subsequent use?

Comment: It is a hint, so like many people may not read on. If I had put the full name in the hint, then it would basically count as a massive spoiler.

Comment: It's literally in a spoiler tag. Using the abbreviation isn't a hint any more than putting the full name would be, but adds that much more frustration. You're obviously hoping the reader will go find out what the thing is, why not just point them straight at it?